# How to solve following LPP using graphical method.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Maximize
$$z = 3x_1 + 2x_2$$
such that
\begin{align}x_1 - x_2 &\geqslant 1\\
x_1 + x_3 &\geqslant 3 \\
 x_1, x_2, x_3 &\geqslant 0 \end{align}

One solution i see says common region is unbounded while in other source gives $Z_{\mathrm{max}}$ as $13$ at $(3,2,0)$.

Comment: A problem with 3 variables is not the optimal problem to solve it graphically. Nevertheless if you increase $x_1$ then z increases and $x_1$ is not restricted by any constraint. Therefore the LP is unbounded.

Comment: Can i also say it like : x1 >=0 and 3 >= x1 >= 0 bcs when x1 > 3, it makes x1 >=0, so this region  3 >= x1 >= 0 with x1 - x2 >= 1 is unbounded one (after plotting) these two.

Comment: Idk, another idea is to evaluate the dual problem. Then you have 2 variables only.

Comment: Consider the basic feasible solution $\hat x=(1,0,2)$. Then $\hat x + \alpha\cdot(0,1,0)$ is feasible for any $\alpha>0$, so clearly the LP is unbounded.

Comment: @Math1000 I think you meant $(1,1,0)$ instead of $(0,1,0)$.

Comment: The Dual would be :$ Min z* = w_1 + 3w_2$ st. $w_1 + w_2 <= 3$ , $w_1 >= -2$ , $w_1, w_2 >= 0$ ? Because by this dual i get bounded solution so, i think am doing some mistake in converting to dual.

Comment: @RobPratt Indeed, I made a typo. Thanks.

Comment: Your dual is incorrect. First rewrite the primal maximization problem with $\le$ constraints. The correct dual problem is infeasible, as you can see by summing the dual constraints and $2w_2\ge 0$ and thus deriving the impossible constraint $0\ge 5$. Alternatively, for the graphical approach you will see that the dual feasible region is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LP is unbounded, here are a couple of perspectives of the feasible region [graphically](https://www.desmos.com/3d/1d5d4a1151):

[image: 2]
[image: 3]

We can observe that for any $x_1$ we choose, there will always be a bigger value of $x_1 + \lambda$ that will create a better $z$ such that $3x_1+2x_2 < 3(x_1 + \lambda) +2x_2$, as there's nothing in the model bounding $x_1$. Graphically, note that the objective function is a plane (in green) that traverses the feasible region like so:

[image: 4]

which confirms this conclusion that it is forever increasing as it traverses $x_1$.